# getElementById alternative $('test1') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I have an HTML forum that is submitting with JavaScript:

```
<form name="test">
Username: <input type="text" id="user"><p id="user1"></p>
Password: <input type="password" id="pass"> <p id="password1"></p>
<button type="submit" onClick="return testChecker()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

While inside the `testChecker` function I have:

```
$('user1').innerHTML = 'Enter Username';
//document.getElementById('user1').innerHTML = 'Enter Username';
```

The problem is when I use `getElementById` it works fine and its displayed. But when I use `$('user1')` it doesn't do anything.

Any idea?

Comment: When accessing an element via a selector, you need to include the `#` when referencing an `id` attribute and `.` for the `class`.

Comment: this is basic jquery

Comment: The `$` function does not exist in native Javascript, it's part of common libraries like jQuery and Mootools.

Comment: Submitting the form won't submit the data since the form controls don't have names, which are required for them to be successful. Also, the submit listener should be on the form, not the button, as forms can be submitted without clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
$('#user1').html("Enter username");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4thx8ans/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Jquery you have to put a `#` before Id names. So use

```
$("#user1")
```

[Jquery Selector Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Put a # in front of user1. JQuery uses that to identify the id.

```
 $('#user1').html('Enter Username');
```

Comment: I think you should use `html();` instead of `innerhtml()` in jquery